# Practical Primes In P

Tags: algorithms

Or rather, practically *applying* PRIMES in P.

I've heard a lot about "PRIMES in P", or the "AKS algorithm". It is, to oversimplify slightly, a very fast way of finding prime numbers.

However, while I've tried reading the original paper (the revised "V3" seems to have vanished from the internet), it's a bit above my comprehension.

I've also tried using Google to find practical implementations of the algorithm, but they too are incomprehensible (which is to say, they're all written in comment-free C++).

Can someone produce a hobbyist/freshman-level explanation of how to implement the AKS algorithm? Or am I misinterpreting exactly what it it does and is for?

Comment: Try also on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you looked at the algorithm in wikipedia's [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)?  Do you have difficulty with understanding how to write a specific part of it? Or is it a more theory based question?  See also CS.SE [When is the AKS primality test actually faster than other tests?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23260/when-is-the-aks-primality-test-actually-faster-than-other-tests)

Comment: @MichaelT I see the words "polynomial congruence relation" and my brain goes "phhht" and emits blue smoke. An ideal answer would be a functioning implementation of a prime sieve using AKS written in pseudocode or clear C or Python.

Comment: And then I notice that there is exactly that listed under the "heading" algorithm. I'll try implementing it tomorrow; if I succeed, I'll answer my own question with it.

Comment: @Schilcote you might want to consider flagging this to be migrated to CS.SE or ask related questions on Math.SE - one one starts delving that far into math it becomes less a programming problem and more to do with the math behind it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let me discuss AKS.  AKS is very important for the **theory**, but not used in practice.  It is not fast, and it isn't a usually used "way of finding prime numbers" ala a sieve.  It is a primality test -- that is, given a number *N*, it answers deterministically whether *N* is prime or not.  There are other methods that run millions of times faster (e.g. BPSW or deterministic M-R below 2^64, APR-CL or ECPP above).  This is even assuming you need a proof -- BPSW plus some M-R tests are good enough for almost everyone and will be faster yet.

The internet *loves* AKS because it sounds like it should be fast.  The only known deterministic polynomial time algorithm!  This is caused by a misunderstanding of randomized algorithms and a failure by the posters to actually implement or even use these methods in practice.

AKS, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) or the [v6 paper](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf), is straightforward at the high level.  There are a few gotchas like making sure you do the logs correctly, and some implementation efficiencies in steps 2/3.  Implementing znorder correctly isn't too hard, especially if you are lax and don't worry too much about efficiency yet (step 5 completely dominates the time).  Step 5 is tricky, because you have to do efficient polynomial exponentiation modulo *N* and a polynomial.  I'd say first get it done and working, then worry about efficient solutions like binary segmentation.

There are lots of implementations around. Programming Praxis has a nice blog post about it, with discussion and a couple implementations.  See [Part 1](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/02/aks-primality-prover-part-1/) and [Part 2](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/05/aks-primality-prover-part-2/).  Part 2 shows implementation of the "V6" algorithm (the updated algorithm from the original authors).

- Bornemann's implementation in Pari.  One of the fastest, uses some improvements and a cool r/s heuristic.
- Programming Praxis has an relatively inefficient version in Scheme.  Easy to follow and the author explains every step.
- Someone posted a nice Python version on Programming Praxis, albeit it only works up to 8 or so digits.
- I have Perl, C, and C+GMP versions on github, with three algorithms each.  The V6 version is the one from the updated paper.  The Voloch+Bornemann version includes the improvements Bornemann shows, and until I implemented the third version, was the fastest open source implementation of AKS.  The third version uses theorem 4.1 from Bernstein's 2004 paper, which includes most published optimizations.  It is >10x faster than the Voloch+Bornemann version.
- Yijun Yuan has a very readable version on github implementing the v6 algorithm using NTL.  It's not fast, but it's quite easy to follow from the paper.
- There are many really bad versions out there (as there are of almost every algorithm one can think of).

One problem with AKS is that you give it a number, it churns away, and says "Prime" or "Composite".  I have seen many implementations that give the wrong answer for some inputs (due to a bug in the implementation).  *Think about that.*  This is supposed to be a proof -- after all, we ran the input through some Miller-Rabin tests, maybe BPSW, we're almost positive the number really is prime, and now we have decided we want as close to 100% certainty as possible.  Yet if we have no good assurance that the program has run correctly, what was the point?  This is why I think ECPP is a far better choice for primality proofs, since it gives a certificate that can be quickly independently checked at any time.  Given that it is also millions of times faster than AKS, it's an easy choice.

Comment: So if a number passed the Miller-Rabin test, and I ask "is this a prime", the possible answers in order of probability are "yes because it is a prime", "no because I got it wrong", "yes but by coincidence, not because it is a prime", and "no because it is composite" (very, very unlikely).

Comment: The proper answers we should return are "definitely prime", "probably prime", and "definitely composite".  The first could apply to numbers under 2^64 where we have easy deterministic tests (e.g. BPSW or known base sets for M-R).  For passing a single round of M-R, the chances could be as high as 1/4 that it is composite. Hence multiple rounds with different bases, to lower that chance to "very, very unlikely".  Software or hardware errors could lead to any result, including saying "composite" for primes, which is not a possible response for correct software/hardware using these methods.